# Collaborative document/code editing, handling undo and conflicts?

Tags: socket.io, google-docs, overwrite, real-time-updates, etherpad

There are many ways of handling undo/redo and conflicts when multiple people are editing documents in realtime.

I'm thinking about every *k* seconds to send the document payload off with a `commit` message to a [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control). For the undo/redo problem, maybe I'll use a [Rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).

But I'm uncertain. what's the best way to resolve merge conflicts and per-user undo/redo?, e.g.: how does Google Docs do it?

Comment: I don't have much experience with real time collab, but I believe Google Docs uses a system called Differential Synchronization: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35605.pdf

Comment: Thanks, interesting article. Maybe add as answer?

Comment: PS: Found this https://github.com/cujojs/jiff on http://www.slideshare.net/briancavalier/differential-sync-and-json-patch-s2-gx-2014

Answer (score 1):

Based on your tags you are using web-technologies.

Taking @DavidYue's advice and using *Differential Synchronization*`[1]`, I would recommend using the [diffsync](https://github.com/janmonschke/diffsync) developed during this thesis`[2]`.

Under the covers it uses [socket.io](http://socket.io), see [example with client, server and DataAdapter (data-source)](https://github.com/janmonschke/diffsync#usage).

---

`[1]` N. Fraser, “[Differential Synchronization](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub35605.html)”, in DocEng’09, Proceedings of the 2009 ACM Symposium on Document Engineering, 2 Penn Plaza, Suite 701, New York, New York 10121-0701, 2009, pp. 13–20.

`[2]` J. Monschke, “[Building a collaborative music production environment using emerging web standards](http://cl.ly/1H111o1w1Z0T)”, Masters Thesis, HTW, Berlin, Germany, 2014.